# extract text lines between two lines with text marks using regex

Tags: python, json, regex, string, file

I have a text file like this:

```
## COL
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueC", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 2, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
                               .
                               .
                               .
{ "Id": n, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueZ", ... "keyN": "valueN"}

## USA
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueC", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 2, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
                               .
                               .
                               .
{ "Id": n, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueZ", ... "keyN": "valueN"}

## ESP
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueC", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 2, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
                               .
                               .
                               .
{ "Id": n, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueZ", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
```

I need to extract just the lines for a specific country using regex and python, for example:

```
## COL
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueC", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 2, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
                               .
                               .
                               .
{ "Id": n, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueZ", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
```

Note: There is no key or value that identifies the country, only those text marks line from the previous example

I try this regex without success:

```
(?<=## COL).*[\w\s]*(?=##})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you shouldn't need regex for this. Why not just check if a line starts with ## and contains the country you're looking for, and then add the following lines to an array until there's a line with another '##' (to indicate another country)

Comment: Good point!, I just thought of extracting the entire text block instead of iterating all the lines, which one will be faster or eficient?

Comment: No need to use regex to extract entire block, just read file line by line and match lines starting with `##`

Comment: But no need **not to use** a regex, this works also quite easily;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex:

```
import re

m = re.search(r'^## COL\n(?:(?!##).)+', text, flags=re.S)

if m:
    print(m.group())
```

More efficient alternative:

```
m = re.search(r'^## COL\n(?:(?:(?!##).*)\n)+', text).group()
```

Output:

```
## COL
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueC", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 2, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueA", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
{ "Id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueB", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
                               .
                               .
                               .
{ "Id": n, "key1": "value1", "key2": "valueZ", ... "keyN": "valueN"}
```

[regex demo option 1](https://regex101.com/r/y8IDB4/1)

[regex demo alternative](https://regex101.com/r/rLeOkB/1) ([with blank lines](https://regex101.com/r/qRn20O/1))

Comment: Thanks mozway for your answer, it worked partially, because there are also blank lines between lines that are from the same block and country, in that case it does not completely extract all the lines for a country

Comment: Easy fix, replace the first `+` with `*` in the alternative, see update ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about `## COL[^#]*` ? It should be sufficient to match the requested pattern ? No look ahead or behind necessary.

See https://regex101.com/r/pc0iaV/1 for demonstration that it works.

Comment: Except if there is a valid `#` somewhere in the text (which isn't the case here, but not an unlikely possibility)

Comment: [Example](https://regex101.com/r/y4BwnU/1)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that ... but the regex is so simple compared to the other ones that I thought it might be worth to be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `re.S` flag you can write the pattern as:

```
^## COL(?:\n(?!## ).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `## COL` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?!## ).*` Match a newline and match the whole line if it does not start with `##`
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xgAmfC/1).